# NG command not doing anything

Tags: angular, npm

No matter which ng command I use, nothing works.

[image]

I have installed the latest angular/cli and I see these in my environment variables PATH

C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm

Has anyone faced this before? Uninstall Angular/Cli and reinstall doesnt work. Restarting PC doesnt work either

Comment: looks like you are using powershell (PS). On Windows client computers, the execution of PowerShell scripts is disabled by default. To allow the execution of PowerShell scripts, which is needed for npm global binaries, you must set the following execution policy `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` (run this command in your powershell). Read more about Execution policies here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @SyedRafay I believe it would have given him an warning if that was the case here

Comment: i would remove `C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin` from you path cause when installing ng it adds some ps files that it uses to run. So maybe it dunno which to execute due to multiple matces

Comment: Tried both non are working also it doesn't work in command prompt either

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
In my environment variables I had this as the order of ng

```
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin 

C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

So it looks like it was looking for the ng.js file before the actual ng command.

I switched them around to look like this and it worked

```
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin
```